# iOS Dev - Developer ID and App ID same on Provisioning Portal

Tags: ios, validation, provisioning

I have a really strange problem.

I am trying to submit an app to Apple ("Ready for upload") and am going through the process of resolving code signing to allow validation.

My Developer ID shown on the Apple Dev site is the same as the ID it shows for the new app.

This is not the case with other apps I have on there.

I have requested a (precious) support incident but have no idea how long this process takes.

Has anyone else had a similar issue? Is it something I'm doing wrong?
 I am a noob at this

Any suggestions / advice gratefully received. Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

Open your Xcode Organizer, and locate your Provisioning Profile that you use for distribution. It will let you know if it is a valid profile or not. If it is valid, then go into the Xcode project settings -> Highlight your project -> Click the "Build Settings" tab -> In the code signing section, change everything to code sign with your distribution profile. I would do this with your Target as well, although I'm not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: @grovesy No problem, let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: Okay - I managed to get the profiles to all be happy bunnies after fiddling some more. The app is now uploaded - let's see what Apple think of it.